# Simple scraping of youtube xml to get a Python list of videos

Tags: python, xml, youtube

I have an xml feed, say:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/bass/fishing/

I want to get the list of hrefs for the videos:

```
 ['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJvVkBcbFFY', 'ht....', ... ]
```

Comment: Have a look at BeautifulSoup. It's a real pleasure to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
import urllib

def get_bass_fishing_URLs():
  results = []
  data = urllib.urlopen(
      'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/bass/fishing/')
  tree = ET.parse(data)
  ns = '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}'
  for entry in tree.findall(ns + 'entry'):
    for link in entry.findall(ns + 'link'):
      if link.get('rel') == 'alternate':
        results.append(link.get('href'))
```

as it appears that what you get are the so-called "alternate" links.  The many small, possible variations if you want something slightly different, I hope, should be clear from the above code (plus the standard Python library [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for ElementTree).

Comment: nice - I forgot about ElementTree. yours is much cleaner than mine :)

Comment: thanks for getting me started with ET; your fully working example helped a lot.  piquadrat gave me exactly what I asked for but then it turned out that I needed the info in <published> as well so this solution proved more adaptable in the wild.

Comment: @sos-sky, you're welcome -- always hard to strike the right balance between "giving a fish" and "teaching to fish", glad to hear that I've struck the right balance this time;-).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Universal Feed Parser](http://www.feedparser.org/), which is an open source RSS and Atom feed parser for Python.

Answer (score 3):

In such a simple case, this should be enough:

```
import re, urllib2
request = urllib2.urlopen("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/bass/fishing/")
text = request.read()
videos = re.findall("http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[\w-]+", text)
```

If you want to do more complicated stuff, parsing the XML will be better suited than regular expressions

Comment: Nice, that does indeed return the list I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse(urllib.urlopen('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/bass/fishing/'))

links = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('link')
hrefs = []
for links in link:
    if link.getAttribute('rel') == 'alternate':
        hrefs.append( link.getAttribute('href') )

hrefs
```

Comment: Thanks for helping to get me going but this returns strange links like:

http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=UIi-fANCngQ

(it should be for link in links above too)

Comment: updated. you can do regex parsing on the inner if statement if you want a certain pattern, or do dom operations on what type of attributes the link element should have.

Comment: I'm confused about it's status as well. urllib2 is more often used by advanced Python 2.x users, however urllib is the module in Python 3...